# HTML/CSS Wrapping data of a cell

Tags: html, css

How can i wrap data in the table. Currently if template name is too long i get a scroll bar. I want it to go in the next line.

```
<table class="selectablePreviousOrder dashboard">
    <tr ng-class-odd="'tableOdd'" ng-class-even="'tableEven'" style="cursor: pointer"
        ng-class="{highlightSelectedSiteRow: selectOrderRow===$index}" ng-repeat="line in listOfProductTemplates | orderBy : '-creationDate'" sglclick="handleSingleClick(line.id)" ng-dblclick="handleSingleClick(line.id)">
        <td width="20%" style="max-width: 162px; overflow: auto;" tooltip="{{line.tooltipLabel}}" tooltip-trigger="{{getTooltipTriggerValue(line)}}" tooltip-append-to-body="true" > <span style="margin-left: 5px; float: left">{{line.templateName}}</span></td>
        <td width="12%" tooltip="{{line.tooltipLabel}}" tooltip-trigger="{{getTooltipTriggerValue(line)}}" tooltip-append-to-body="true"><span style="margin-left: 5px; float: left">{{line.requestType}}</span></td>
        <td width="24%" tooltip="{{line.tooltipLabel}}" tooltip-trigger="{{getTooltipTriggerValue(line)}}" tooltip-append-to-body="true"><span style="margin-left: 10px; float: left">{{line.product}}</span></td>
        <td width="18%" tooltip="{{line.tooltipLabel}}" tooltip-trigger="{{getTooltipTriggerValue(line)}}" tooltip-append-to-body="true"><span style="margin-left: 10px; float: left">{{line.creationDate |  date : expiryDateFormatter}}</span></td>
        <td width="19%" tooltip="{{line.tooltipLabel}}" tooltip-trigger="{{getTooltipTriggerValue(line)}}" tooltip-append-to-body="true" ><span style="margin-left: 15px; float: left">{{line.creatorName }}</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle of what you currently have and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks i found a solution.. in the span i used a style  <span style="margin-left: 5px; float: left; max-width: 161px;  word-wrap: break-word">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can do this with CSS using:

style="word-wrap: break-word;"

Have fun coding :)